# Reading from second column of excel inside a for loop in Katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio, data-driven-tests

I have a for loop which reads data from a particular column "A" of an excel sheet.

Now, for this for loop in the first iteration I need to read specific rows like row 1 and row 3 from another column "B" of excel. 
Then in the second iteration I want to read row 2 and row 4 of the same column "B", and then in the third iteration I want to read row 5 and row 7 from the same column "B".

How can I achieve this, my main for loop is working fine, but somehow I am unable to read specific rows.

Answer (score 1):

I found the instruction at https://www.katalon.com/videos/get-datas-excel-file-katalon-studio/. Hope that it help